# random events, show if $P(B')=0.4$ then $P(A\cap B') \le 0.4$

Tags: probability

Let $A,B$ be random events included in $\Omega$ space. Show that if $P(B')=0.4$ then $P(A\cap B') \le 0.4$

so my idea is to show that $P(A \cap B') \subseteq P(B')$ then we have $P(A \cap B')\le 0.4$

is it correct ?

Comment: Notation $P(A \cap B') \subseteq P(B')$ does not make sense. It is either $P(A \cap B') \leq P(B')$ or $A \cap B' \subseteq B'$.

Comment: right sorry, stupid mistake but apart from it rest is ok ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, the probability you pick 1 sock from a drawer randomly is black is bigger than the probability you pick a pair which are black...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be a random set. Sorry, dont know the mathematical words in english
[image: My solution via jpeg]